# Need help creating reminders on iOS 5

Tags: ios, reminders

After upgrading form iOS 5 beta to the final release, I cannot create any new reminders.

The issue seems to be caused by the fact that there is no reminder lists to which to add a new reminder, but I can't find any way to add a new list to the app.

In the screenshot, you can see I have the "Completed" list of tasks, that I made with one of the earlier betas of iOS 5, but there are no other lists.

[image]

The system's language is set to Italian, I hope that the screenshot is clear enough to show the situation.

Comment: Are you using iPhone 4S, or upgraded the iphone 4 with iOS 5?? I have upgraded iphone 4 with iOS 5 and I see the same issue..i think its issue with upgrade only..

Comment: iPhone 4 updated to iOS 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the iPad Reminders app, there is no + button when viewing **Completed** tasks.

What happens when you click on **Data**? Can you then add items?

**Edit**

It looks like [others are having the same problem](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3376991?start=15&tstart=0). Does [this reply](https://discussions.apple.com/message/16397230#16397230) work for you:

> here's the solution that seems to work... have tried it, reversed it, and retried and it worked twice.  Turn on reminders in icloud.  go to reminder app.... + should now be there.  i then turned off reminders becasue it seems to just drain the battery... but select option to keep remdiners on the iphone when it prompts you.

Comment: In italian "Data" means "date", and brings me to a calendar-like view.

Comment: Ah right. I've added to my answer, with a possible solution.

Comment: I turned on reminders on iCloud and turned it off, now lists are there and I can add new lists and new tasks. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On the screen you are showing in the screenshot, click on the button with three lines. On the screen that lists the lists, click on the "Edit" button and you'll see a text entry at the bottom of the list of lists that says "Create New List..." Click it and you'll have a new list.

Comment: I don't have a "Create new list" button in the list of lists screen. This is the main issue I think.